# Understanding DIQKD protocol, a few questions

Tags: quantum-computing

I'm refering to this paper [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/pubs/diqkd.pdf) ***"Fully Device-Independent Quantum Key Distribution"*** (Umesh Vazirani and Thomas Vidick) and unfortunately there are many things I don't understand.

1) Page 3: by the word round, what do the authors actually mean? Is it right to say it's basically how many times Alice and Bob use their own devices?

2) Page 3, Testing section: this equality `aᵢ ⊕ bᵢ = xᵢ ∧ yᵢ` I was told it describes the requirement of the CHSH game. Alice input can be anything belonging to the set `{0,1,2}` while Bob's input can only be an element of the following set`{0,1}`. Their output can be `0` or `1`, respectively.
The paper says ***"They compute the fraction of inputs in B that satisfy the CHSH condition aᵢ ⊕ bᵢ = xᵢ ∧ yᵢ..***". My understanding is: if ⊕ is exclusive OR and ∧ is logical AND then the following makes sense:  `aᵢ=1 bᵢ=0`    `1 ⊕ 0 = 1 ∧ 1` Is that correct? If I'm right what does the following expression mean? ***"If this fraction is smaller than cos2 π=8 − η they abort the protocol***"

---

***[Cross-posted on quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/9333/55)***

Comment: It is advised to quote the paragraphs from the paper you are asking about and to write the name of the paper and the authors in the question in case the link gone broken

Comment: I suppose I did what you suggested..

Answer (score 3):

All of these are defined in page 2 of that paper.

1) A **round** is a single interaction with the device: Alice gives it an input, Bob gives is  an input, and the device outputs a bit to Alice and a bit to Bob.

2) While Alice's **input** is from the set $\{0,1,2\}$, the output she gets from the device, $a_i$, is a single bit. Then, the equation $a_i \oplus b_i = x_i \wedge y_i$ is on bits (the case of $x_i=2$ is treated separately). This equation is indeed the [CHSH condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHSH_inequality). If the bits where classical, the expected CHSH term is bounded by $2$, while if the system is quantum, values of up to $2\sqrt2$ are possible. By measuring the amount of times the equation holds you can estimate the value of the expected CHSH term, and if it is large enough, this implies the generation of "true" randomness.

There is a longer and more detailed version of that paper in 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.1810

Comment: thanks for your reply...unfortunately I still don't understand...<They compute the fraction of inputs in B that satisfy the CHSH condition....etc> Could you please give an example? I believe the fraction of inputs of B is a number...since the subset B is the subset whose elements are numbers (1,2,3,4...the interactions)...am I right? sorry...but I was given a tough task...thanks very much

Comment: Not sure I get you. They perform many rounds and count how many satisfy $a \oplus b = x \wedge y$, and how many rounds don't satisfy it. If the fraction of "good" rounds is too low, this might mean no quantumness was involved-so they abort. The exact fraction is analyzed in that paper...

Comment: thanks again.I'll try to sum up what you have stated so far also adding something I got from the paper
if inputs: {0,1} the output should satisfy the CHSH equation (a⊕b=x∧y) and if it holds for a large number of times it means that the sequence is truly random
if inputs: {2,1} the output must satisfy a=b since |a XOR b =0 |
if inputs: {2,0} any output is valid
Output: {0,1} Is all correct? I think I'll need your help soon,,thanks very much